# Having trouble installing barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper via composer - class not found error in Laravel 4 project

Tags: php, github, laravel-4, composer-php, packagist

I have the following **composer.json** file for my **Laravel 4.2.x** project:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*",
        "way/generators": "2.*",
        "laracasts/flash": "~1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~1.11@dev",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Latheesan/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Latheesan": "app/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

This has been working fine until today. When I ran the **composer update** command, I got the following error:

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class
>   'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider' not
>   found","file":"C:\wamp\www\projectfolder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}Script
>   php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned
>   with an error

It looks like the package that caused the problem is `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` version `~1.11@dev`

On the project's [home page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) on github, it says:

### For Laravel 4.x, [check version 1.8](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/tree/1.8)

But that appears to be a dead link.

So, what is the correct require line to use on the `composer.json` file, for this package that supports laravel 4.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it, this is the line I needed on my `composer.json`

```
"barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.11.*@dev"
```

It was mentioned on the packagist.org site: https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i have got solution: (For Laravel 5, but think can work also in Laravel 4)

1. remove line about `"barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper"` from require array
   on composer.json file.
2. run the next line: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

And you will got your laravel project updated with the last version of barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper extension

(More info: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

---

I have tried with these lines:

- "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*"
- "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*@dev"
- "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.11.*@dev"

For laravel 5 and i got the next error on composer update:

barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v1.2.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock dev-master#6d705c1a0f9e2a6d73d2e9ec0e538b9dfaf4315f -> no matching package
 found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

my composer version was outdated and thats the problem. I updated my composer to latest version 1.7 and the problem is gone.